# Menu Bar missing after using Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I was trying to use BottomAppBar but i was getting a error saying `The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents`

So i changed the style to Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar

But the problem is that my menubar now is missing but when i click on it i can see my menu itens.So it is there but no visible for the user.

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Dashboard2"
    android:background="#fff"
   >




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">


    </LinearLayout>

<!--    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--        android:background="@color/darkgray"-->
<!--        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">-->

<!--    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>-->
 
    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:text="Minha Dashboard"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="92dp"

            />

<!--        <ImageView-->
<!--            android:layout_width="62dp"-->
<!--            android:layout_height="62dp"-->
<!--            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
<!--            android:src="@drawable/img"/>-->

    </RelativeLayout>




    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">



        </RelativeLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="14dp"
            >

            <!-- Row 1 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#303F9F"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Visão Geral"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#303F9F"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_store_24"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Logística"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#303F9F"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_credit_card_24"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Pagamentos"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#303F9F">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_date_range_24"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Antecipação"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <!-- Row 2 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#303F9F"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_list_24"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Extrato"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#303F9F"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Vendas"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/darkgray"
        app:itemIconTint="#0099FF"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[Print of the invisible menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDHCh.png)

Styles.xml:

```
  <resources>
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">
                true
            </item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    
    
        </style>
        <style name="SCBSwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
            <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/black</item>
    
            <!-- inactive thumb color -->
            <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#ffff
            </item>
    
            <!-- inactive track color (30% transparency) -->
            <item name="android:colorForeground">#42221f1f
            </item>
        </style>
        <style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        </style>
    
        <style name="AppTheme3" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    
    
    
    
    
    
        </style>
        <style name="BottomMenuColor" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        </style>
    
    
    
    </resources>
```

In this activity i'm using AppTheme2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`But the problem is that my menubar now is missing.`

It's not missing, it's actually present there just the background color and the color of your menu item icon are being set the same due to which this is the issue.

Either change the menu icon color or change the theme.

Comment: but my menu bar is a black hamburguer icon like [this](https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/threelines.png)

Comment: And so is your theme that u hv set...darkactionbar.

Comment: Set the icon to white and it will work or else change the theme.

Comment: What theme could i use if i don't want to change it to white?

Comment: Light.lightactionbar

Comment: It can not resolve Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.LightActionBar

Comment: What is the Error msg?? Entire string.

Comment: AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.LightActionBar

Comment: Go for material components.lightavtionbar

Comment: Thanks for you help

Comment: Happy Coding! Welcome!